# My caesar cipher does not output any encrypted message

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
#Caesar Cipher Muntanga
FinalMessage=""
Mode=""
MessageNumber=""
while Mode!="encrypt" and Mode!="decrypt":
     Mode = input("Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?")
     Mode = Mode.lower()

Message = input("Please enter the message you wish to encrypt:")
Message = Message.upper()

Key = input("Please enter your key:")
Key = int(Key)

if Key < 1:
     print("This program does not encrypt backwards. Please restart and enter a key between 1-25")
     raise SystemExit

elif Key > 25:
    print("You are looping round the alphabet. Please restar the program and enter a key between 1-25")
    raise SystemExit



if Mode == "encrypt":
     for i in range(0, len(Message)):
          if MessageNumber.isalpha():
               if MessageNumber.isupper():
                   MessageNumber = ord(Message[i])
                   MessageNumber = MessageNumber + Key
                   if MessageNumber > 90:
                       MessageNumber = MessageNumber - 26
                   FinalMessage = FinalMessage + chr(MessageNumber)
               elif MessageNumber.islower():
                    MessageNumber = ord(Message[i])
                    MessageNumber = MessageNumber + Key
                    if MessageNumber > 122:
                       MessageNumber = MessageNumber - 26
                    FinalMessage = FinalMessage + chr(MessageNumber)

print("Your encrypted message is:")
print(FinalMessage)
raise SystemExit
```

**My cipher outputs blank message (check image)**
[Image of failed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQQFU.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `MessageNumber` before it has any meaningful value. You initialized `MessageNumber` with an empty string at the beginning of the script, but since this variable has to be set for each character of the input string, you don't need to initialize it "globally".

When you remove the initialization, you will quickly see a meaningful error saying that `MessageNumber` is NoneType in the line `if MessageNumber.isalpha():`.

Additionally, you can deduplicate some lines by moving those calls one level higher:

```
if Mode == "encrypt":
     for i in range(0, len(Message)):
          MessageChar = Message[i]
          MessageNumber = ord(MessageChar)
          if MessageChar.isalpha():
               MessageNumber = MessageNumber + Key
               if MessageChar.isupper():
                   if MessageNumber > 90:
                       MessageNumber = MessageNumber - 26
               elif MessageChar.islower():
                    if MessageNumber > 122:
                       MessageNumber = MessageNumber - 26
               FinalMessage = FinalMessage + chr(MessageNumber)
```

Comment: now it says "f MessageNumber.isalpha():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isalpha'"

Comment: I've introduced another variable that holds the character in addition to the variable that holds the character code. There are of course a million different ways to solve this.

Comment: It's pretty clear. It says that `MessageNumber` is of type `int` and instances of that type don't have a `isalpha` function on them. Strings have such functions.

Answer (score 1):

since someone else pointed out your problem i will instead show you an easier way to do ceasar cipher shifts

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lc,ascii_uppercase as uc,maketrans as trans

def encode(m,rotation_amount):
    alphabet = lc+uc
    rotated_alphabet = (lc[rotation_amount:]+lc[:rotation_amount]
                       +uc[rotation_amount:]+uc[:rotation_amount])
    return m.translate(trans(alphabet,rotated_alphabet))


print encode("how are YoU")
```